# SwitchCompat OnCheckedChangeListener called on every orientation change of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes, oncheckedchanged, switchcompat

I have an activity which hosts a fragment and the problem is that, on every orientation change and only if the switch was in the checked state, the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called. How do I solve this problem? Thanks!

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private SwitchMaterial switchMaterial;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        switchMaterial = view.findViewById(R.id.switch_material);
        switchMaterial.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Switch is checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Switch is NOT checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution I found is to check, in the `onCheckedChanged` method, if the `buttonView` (the Switch) was actually toggled by the user and not after recovering the `savedInstanceState` after an orientation change, for example:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // Handle the checked state
        } else {
            // Handle the NOT checked state
        }
    }
}
```

If there are more elegant answers, I'm totally waiting for them!