# Ho do I properly handle TextView bound to Switch on orientation change, in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes, android-togglebutton, android-switch

As the title suggests, how do I avoid the `TextView` to lose its text after an orientation change?
Notice how the `TextView` is bound to the `Switch`: the initial text (defined in XML) is *OFF* (because the `Switch` is initially in the off state) and, on every `Switch` state change, the `TextView`'s text is changed accordingly.

**Expected behavior:**

1. Open app: `Switch` is off, `TextView` is *OFF*
2. Turn on the `Switch`: `TextView` is *ON*
3. Rotate the device: `Switch` stays on and `TextView` stays *ON* as well

**Actual behavior:**

1. Open app: `Switch` is off, `TextView` is *OFF*
2. Turn on the `Switch`: `TextView` is *ON*
3. Rotate the device: `Switch` stays on, but `TextView` is *OFF*

The following happens because the `Fragment` is redrawn and since the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called on every orientation change (My question: [SwitchCompat OnCheckedChangeListener called on every orientation change of Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54281040/5495385)), but the handling only happens if the `Switch` was actually pressed (to avoid the problem in the question above), the `TextView` is drawn with the default text in XML.

**Behavior without isPressed():**

1. Open app: `Switch` is off, `TextView` is *OFF*
2. Turn on the `Switch`: `TextView` is *ON*
3. Rotate the device: `Switch` "stays" on and `TextView` "stays" *ON* as well **BUT** the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called again, and I want to avoid this because I want a call there **ONLY** if the user actually toggled the `Switch`

**MainFragment.java:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private AppCompatTextView appCompatTextView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        appCompatTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.app_compat_textview);
        final SwitchMaterial switchMaterial = rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch_material);
        switchMaterial.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
            if (isChecked) {
                appCompatTextView.setText("ON");
            } else {
                appCompatTextView.setText("OFF");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment is getting destroyed on every orientation change. Hence all UI elements are redrawn. What you need is to save and restore fragment instance on orientation change. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/5802513) for how to.